# python openCV codec info

Tags: python, opencv, video, codec

Let's say there are some mov files. I want to know what codec each mov is using.
Can anyone help me?
I need to get "h264" as in the image, not Input(AVC1).

```
import cv2
import glob

mov_files = glob.glob('*.mp4')

for eachFile in mov_files:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(eachFile)
    file_length = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    print(file_length)
    codec ??
    print(codec)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share the code snippet instead of its photo

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the 4 character code of the video codec using below:

```
h = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
codec = chr(h&0xff) + chr((h>>8)&0xff) + chr((h>>16)&0xff) + chr((h>>24)&0xff)
```

**UPDATE:**

With OpenCV only the FourCC information for the video codec is possible to get. No further information on codec is available. You can refer to the link: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

And also the list of FourCC codes: http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php

So as per this question, you can get the FourCC code information only by using OpenCV. For further details on the codec you may need to use other libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but what I get is input info. I need to get Video codec info.(ex, DnxHD, h264,,,,,,etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look for other libraries.